# Why is the binomial model preferable to the hypergeometric model?

Tags: distributions, sampling, modeling, binomial-distribution, model

working through notes on the formulation of statistical models.

Looking at the following example of estimating a population proportion.
The following is said:
"estimation of a proportion is often based on a random sample of size n drawn **without replacement** from some population with N individuals.
the appropriate statistical model is the hypergeometric distribution.
However the hypergeometric distribution can be approximated by the binomial distribution(which is a statistical model for the number of observations with some property of interest in a random sample with replacement.
The difference between the two models is negligible if n is much smaller than N, and in such a case, the **binomial model is preferred**."

My questions are:

1)why can we approximate the hypergeometric distribution by the binomial distribution when n is much smaller than N?

2) why is the binomial distribution preferred to the hypergeometric distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to 1) was provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330553/proof-that-the-hypergeometric-distribution-with-large-n-approaches-the-binomia)

2) The binomial distribution is less expensive to evaluate numerically, and it also leads to simpler analytical expressions in general.